# What is a good way to model this set of time-series data? What might the distribution be? (Personal expenses)

Tags: probability, distributions, finance

I'm trying to make some sense out of this data, but have been having some trouble.
The data is of personal expenses made during the last 90 days.
How would one go about the modeling this type of data?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Expenses against the Date]

[image: Distribution of the Expenses]

```
2015.5.2    $14.40 
2015.5.2 $2.40 
2015.5.2    $1.50 
2015.5.2 $10.50 
2015.5.3    $2.80 
2015.5.3 $4.80 
2015.5.4    $3.20 
2015.5.4 $30.00 
2015.5.5    $13.00 
2015.5.5 $35.00 
2015.5.6    $3.00 
2015.5.6 $5.70 
2015.5.7    $3.20 
2015.5.7 $8.00 
2015.5.7    $73.50 
2015.5.7 $1.00 
2015.5.8    $4.80 
2015.5.8 $3.00 
2015.5.8    $6.50 
2015.5.9 $2.70 
2015.5.9    $11.00 
2015.5.9 $4.20 
2015.5.10   $93.30 
2015.5.10 $9.36 
2015.5.10   $1.05 
2015.5.10 $30.00 
2015.5.11   $3.20 
2015.5.11 $0.26 
2015.5.11   $7.80 
2015.5.11 $1.20 
2015.5.11   $126.63 
2015.5.12 $6.96 
2015.5.12   $3.20 
2015.5.12 $209.32 
2015.5.12   $14.00 
2015.5.13 $6.60 
2015.5.13   $50.00 
2015.5.14 $2.50 
2015.5.14   $46.00 
2015.5.15 $10.32 
2015.5.16   $1.60 
2015.5.17 $60.00 
2015.5.17   $4.50 
2015.5.17 $5.00 
2015.5.17   $30.00 
2015.5.17 $5.45 
2015.5.18   $1.80 
2015.5.20 $3.20 
2015.5.20   $5.00 
2015.5.20 $29.00 
2015.5.21   $10.40 
2015.5.22 $8.52 
2015.5.22   $3.00 
2015.5.22 $19.90 
2015.5.22   $53.00 
2015.5.23 $67.00 
2015.5.23   $9.72 
2015.5.23 $8.00 
2015.5.24   $8.00 
2015.5.24 $30.00 
2015.5.24   $18.80 
2015.5.24 $18.00 
2015.5.25   $34.68 
2015.5.25 $5.00 
2015.5.26   $2.10 
2015.5.27 $8.40 
2015.5.27   $3.40 
2015.5.27 $20.00 
2015.5.27   $1.90 
2015.5.27 $7.10 
2015.5.28   $3.20 
2015.5.28 $26.48 
2015.5.28   $22.20 
2015.5.29 $3.50 
2015.5.29   $6.80 
2015.5.29 $2.00 
2015.5.29   $3.50 
2015.5.30 $2.00 
2015.5.30   $12.00 
2015.5.30 $5.00 
2015.5.30   $4.10 
2015.5.31 $4.80 
2015.5.31   $13.45 
2015.5.31 $6.35 
2015.6.1    $2.50 
2015.6.1 $100.00 
2015.6.1    $10.70 
2015.6.2 $3.20 
2015.6.2    $4.50 
2015.6.3 $59.35 
2015.6.3    $40.00 
2015.6.4 $41.50 
2015.6.5    $4.20 
2015.6.5 $5.00 
2015.6.5    $0.90 
2015.6.5 $23.00 
2015.6.5    $4.30 
2015.6.5 $1.20 
2015.6.6    $2.80 
2015.6.6 $4.20 
2015.6.6    $8.20 
2015.6.7 $10.00 
2015.6.7    $51.00 
2015.6.7 $13.20 
2015.6.8    $2.90 
2015.6.8 $14.00 
2015.6.9    $1.20 
2015.6.9 $20.00 
2015.6.9    $10.00 
2015.6.10 $3.00 
2015.6.10   $0.18 
2015.6.10 $5.50 
2015.6.10   $214.72 
2015.6.11 $3.00 
2015.6.11   $97.87 
2015.6.12 $9.40 
2015.6.12   $3.70 
2015.6.13 $10.90 
2015.6.13   $35.00 
2015.6.13 $3.70 
2015.6.13   $24.00 
2015.6.14 $14.04 
2015.6.14   $15.00 
2015.6.14 $11.10 
2015.6.14   $11.00 
2015.6.15 $2.60 
2015.6.16   $10.08 
2015.6.16 $3.00 
2015.6.16   $4.10 
2015.6.16 $20.00 
2015.6.16   $10.00 
2015.6.18 $5.28 
2015.6.18   $3.80 
2015.6.19 $0.90 
2015.6.19   $35.00 
2015.6.19 $4.32 
2015.6.20   $6.50 
2015.6.20 $34.00 
2015.6.21   $6.20 
2015.6.21 $4.10 
2015.6.21   $1.60 
2015.6.21 $6.30 
2015.6.22   $2.70 
2015.6.22 $1.00 
2015.6.22   $4.99 
2015.6.22 $10.00 
2015.6.23   $6.00 
2015.6.23 $50.90 
2015.6.23   $279.00 
2015.6.24 $5.70 
2015.6.24   $12.00 
2015.6.24 $65.00 
2015.6.24   $5.00 
2015.6.25 $3.00 
2015.6.26   $9.96 
2015.6.26 $0.80 
2015.6.27   $5.52 
2015.6.27 $1.40 
2015.6.27   $1.50 
2015.6.27 $9.50 
2015.6.29   $5.50 
2015.6.29 $16.60 
2015.6.29   $55.00 
2015.6.30 $3.30 
2015.6.30   $99.00 
2015.6.30 $7.30 
2015.6.30   $2.80 
2015.6.30 $55.00 
2015.6.30   $11.00 
2015.6.30 $4.50 
2015.7.1    $10.20 
2015.7.1 $100.30 
2015.7.2    $8.80 
2015.7.2 $24.00 
2015.7.3    $2.42 
2015.7.3 $24.35 
2015.7.3    $39.05 
2015.7.4 $30.00 
2015.7.4    $8.75 
2015.7.4 $4.50 
2015.7.4    $30.90 
2015.7.4 $5.00 
2015.7.5    $4.50 
2015.7.5 $3.20 
2015.7.6    $3.00 
2015.7.6 $3.90 
2015.7.6    $40.90 
2015.7.7 $4.50 
2015.7.7    $2.90 
2015.7.7 $7.60 
2015.7.8    $3.50 
2015.7.8 $6.80 
2015.7.9    $3.00 
2015.7.9 $32.00 
2015.7.9    $14.20 
2015.7.10 $3.00 
2015.7.10   $85.00 
2015.7.10 $0.26 
2015.7.10   $8.90 
2015.7.10 $381.72 
2015.7.10   $14.00 
2015.7.11 $15.84 
2015.7.11   $2.00 
2015.7.11 $6.02 
2015.7.11   $2.40 
2015.7.11 $7.00 
2015.7.12   $5.20 
2015.7.12 $3.70 
2015.7.13   $101.28 
2015.7.13 $12.30 
2015.7.13   $15.00 
2015.7.13 $8.90 
2015.7.14   $2.70 
2015.7.14 $7.00 
2015.7.14   $14.30 
2015.7.14 $7.50 
2015.7.14   $8.60 
2015.7.14 $2.00 
2015.7.15   $4.60 
2015.7.15 $5.50 
2015.7.16   $94.60 
2015.7.16 $74.14 
2015.7.16   $12.32 
2015.7.16 $2.60 
2015.7.16   $1.30 
2015.7.17 $28.70 
2015.7.17   $77.17 
2015.7.17 $70.00 
2015.7.18   $4.10 
2015.7.18 $40.00 
2015.7.19   $7.80 
2015.7.20 $3.40 
2015.7.20   $4.50 
2015.7.21 $9.40 
2015.7.21   $28.00 
2015.7.21 $4.10 
2015.7.22   $9.60 
2015.7.22 $7.50 
2015.7.22   $3.50 
2015.7.23 $1.20 
2015.7.23   $14.00 
2015.7.23 $11.00 
2015.7.23   $6.50 
2015.7.23 $3.50 
2015.7.23   $12.00 
2015.7.24 $10.80 
2015.7.24   $3.00 
2015.7.24 $43.50 
2015.7.25   $335.00 
2015.7.25 $10.68 
2015.7.25   $1.90 
2015.7.25 $47.40 
2015.7.25   $218.00 
2015.7.25 $55.50 
2015.7.25   $25.00 
2015.7.25 $100.00 
2015.7.26   $47.00 
2015.7.26 $5.00 
2015.7.26   $4.10 
2015.7.26 $1.60 
2015.7.26   $4.60 
2015.7.27 $2.70 
2015.7.27   $1.20 
2015.7.27 $14.30 
2015.7.27   $0.65 
2015.7.28 $2.20 
2015.7.28   $28.60 
2015.7.29 $7.80 
2015.7.29   $6.00 
2015.7.30 $9.24 
2015.7.30   $3.10 
2015.7.30 $3.00 
2015.7.30   $3.50 
2015.7.31 $5.20 
2015.7.31   $5.00
```

Comment: Please be more specific.  one does not simply "model" data without a particular goal in mind, that would not make any sense.  What is it, specifically, that you aim to accomplish with a model?

Comment: I would like to start by finding a distribution that best fits the data

Comment: In that case, it would be helpful to present a histogram or density plot.  Also you can try plotting a histogram/density of $ln(expenses)$ so long as none are equal to 0.  Generally price data is more friendly when it's logged.  You can also try plotting the ACF of the logged expenses as that will help gauge stationary, which would be needed if you want to fit an unconditional distribution.

Comment: Thanks Zach! I feel like I know what I need to look further into!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are definitely many approaches how to cope with this. My **first idea** would have the following steps:

1. To fit the histogram by a probability distribution (exponential, log-normal, gamma) $f(X)$.
2. To transform the data you have to quantiles, using the cumulative density function $Y_k=F(X=x_k)$.
3. To use a time series model with auto-regression (e.g. ARIMA) on $Y_k$ with the application of logit (for combination of logit and ARIMA see e.g. [this](https://conferences.telecom-bretagne.eu/asmda2005/IMG/pdf/proceedings/627.pdf)).

Using this, you will have a time-series just the pointer $Y$ on the interval $[0, 1]$ and you will also have a way how to transform the pointer back to the original values $X$.

A **completely different solution** could be just to apply logarithm on your data and use standard time-series models. The backward transformation would be then exponential.

In **both approaches** you would use transformation-timeseries-backwardtransformation sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You may apply a Box Cox transformation so your data looks more like a normal distribution. Then you can do your analysis and revert back using the inverse transform. 
[image: Box Cox Transform]

You can also use some tests and plots, like Shapiro-Wilk, Anderson-Darling, etc to evaluate the best lambda in the Box Cox transform

The boxcoxnc function in the AID R package provides several test to help you choose the best lambda for the Box Cox transform.